# How to register a service with org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceRegistry 7.57.0

Tags: drools, kie

I upgraded to drools7.57.0 (org.kie 7.57.0) in my grails4.0.11 plugin. In my plugin code (using the old drools 6.5.0.Final), I register a "KieStoreServices" bean (kstore) using:

```
org.kie.internal.utils.ServiceRegistryImpl.getInstance().registerLocator(KieStoreServices.class, {
  return applicationContext.getBean('kstore')
})
```

Now, in the new version, I see there's no "org.kie.internal.utils.ServiceRegistryImpl" anymore while there's "org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceRegistry" which doesn't have "registerLocator". How can I do the registration in this case? How can I add/register a service?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just an aside, this is one of those 'caveat emptor' things that happens when you muck around with internal undocumented APIs that aren't designed or intended for end-use.  :-/

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas so there's no way? :/ -_-

Comment: There may still be a way, but it's highly unlikely you'll get someone to answer. And the next time you upgrade you'll have potentially the same issue if you keep relying on internal, undocumented, and unpublished APIs. It's more likely that you'll end up having to figure it out yourself. You're better off using the library like it was intended.